# React: how to keep a running total in a game

Tags: reactjs

I have a Container component which manages gameId for a Game component in its state.
At the end of the game, the user gets a score.
The user hits playAgain and I want to keep a running total of totalScore by adding userScore to it.

*updated*

To change the state in the top component Container, I need to bind this in a function and send it down to Footer. 
Before I was trying to call this function and got an error "do not change state within a render()"

```
  this.props.addToTotalScore(this.props.userScore);
```

The code:

```
class Container extends React.Component {    

 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { 
   gameId:1,
    ...
   totalScore:0
 };
}

  addToTotalScore(val){
      this.setState({ totalScore: this.state.totalScore + val }); 
  }
 .....
 render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Game 
                key={this.state.gameId}
                ...

                addToTotalScore={this.addToTotalScore.bind(this)}
            />
        </div>
    ); 
 }
}
```

And Game:

```
class Game extends React.Component {

  ....

    finishGame(gameState) {

    let completedTime = this.secondsRemaining;
    let userScore = 0;
    if (gameState === "won"){

        let wrongGuesses = 3 - this.state.wrongGuesses.length;
        userScore = wrongGuesses < 1? 1: wrongGuesses;


    }
    // want to change the userScore and update the totalScore here
    this.setState({ userScore: userScore });
    this.props.addToTotalScore(this.props.userScore);
   });

    clearInterval(this.playTimerId);
    return gameState;
  }
```

What I did to solve this was to create a variable and set the Game state and then use the same variable rather than calling props.userState to update the total. This updated the total count as expected.

In finishGame:

```
 ...
 let wrongGuesses = 3 - this.state.wrongGuesses.length;

 let _userScore = wrongGuesses < 1? 1: wrongGuesses;
 this.setState({userScore: _userScore});
 this.props.addToTotalScore(_userScore);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'calling it here is a problem bc of setting state within a render()'? Because I don't see where you update within state in render method

Comment: Not really sure what your issue is, but if you mean that you are setting your state somewhere in your render method then you shouldn't be doing that

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not actually a question about React, it's about your game. What you're asking is: when is the best time to add the score to the total score.

The simplest answer is: once the game round is finished. Obviously this depends on your game. How do you decide that the round has finished? is it based on a timer? or based on a specific event?

If your `finishGame` method runs when the game round is finished, then yeah it's a good place to add to the total score. I don't see why this would affect `render`. I don't understand what you mean by saying 
`Adding this bound function and calling it here is a problem bc of setting state within a render().` You are passing it as a prop inside the render() method, this is not the same as calling it. Once it is called, the state will change and React will run render() again.